# Is there a way to deploy a react native app without going through the apple store route

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, deployment, create-react-app

What is the possible solution to hosting a React native ios app without going through the route of the ios store

The project is stuck right now and nothing has been tried since the only route is to go through the IOS store or some services out there...a more seamless way might seem more logical

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the only path in case you intended to reach a public audience. There's some hope to have another alternative in the future for the EU market - https://www.reuters.com/technology/apple-prepares-allow-alternative-app-stores-iphones-ipads-bloomberg-news-2022-12-13/

Comment: A react native app is still an iOS app. It being react native doesn't affect in any way the distribution mechanisms for iPhone. If you are deploying privately, or to a company for example, then it doesn't have to go through the store.